# How to show only Specific Categories on Specific Pages in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, categories

I'm new in wordpress development. I want to know how to show specific categories on specific page in wordpress. I need to do it in my project.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that questions asking for general help or recommendations are discouraged: See [Allowed Topics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This is not a code-writing service, you are expected to have researched your issue and made attempts to solve it before posting. Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

**displays a list of categories as links.**

Basically, you have to call this function `wp_list_categories();` in the place you want to see your categories listed.

And use this option `include` which accepts a list of category IDs to display.

Like this

```
$args = array(
    'hide_empty' => 0, //Show me all the categories, even the empty ones
    'orderby' => 'count', //which accepts a string. You can pick from the following options: ID to order the categories by their ID (no, really?), name to sort them alphabetically (the default value), slug to sort them in the alphabetical order of their slugs, and count to order by the number of posts they contain.
    'order' => 'DESC', //The chosen order can be reversed by setting DESC (descending) as a value for the order option (by default this option is set to ASC (ascending)).
    'include' => '15,16,9'
);

wp_list_categories($args);
```

---

**another way to display categories using `get_categories();` function**

```
$categories = get_categories( array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order'   => 'ASC',
    'include' => '15,16,9'
) );

foreach( $categories as $category ) {
    $category_link = sprintf( 
        '<a href="%1$s" alt="%2$s">%3$s</a>',
        esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ),
        esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts in %s', 'textdomain' ), $category->name ) ),
        esc_html( $category->name )
    );

    echo '<p>' . sprintf( esc_html__( 'Category: %s', 'textdomain' ), $category_link ) . '</p> ';
    echo '<p>' . sprintf( esc_html__( 'Description: %s', 'textdomain' ), $category->description ) . '</p>';
    echo '<p>' . sprintf( esc_html__( 'Post Count: %s', 'textdomain' ), $category->count ) . '</p>';
}
```

Difference between `wp_list_categories` and `get_categories`
The WordPress functions `get_categories()` and `wp_list_categories()` are almost the same. They are using almost the same parameters but there is a difference between them:

The `get_categories()` function returns an array of category objects matching the query parameters.
The `wp_list_categories()` displays a list of categories as links.
WordPress developer documention:

**get_categories():** http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories

**wp_list_categories():** http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_categories

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did

```
[product_categories ids="170, 189"]
```

You can get the category IDs in the URL of the categories. Just go to your category and in the url you'll see something like this "product_cat&tag_ID=165&post_type=product" the Id=# is the ID :P